# how to resize figures within a subplot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, subplot

I'm trying to resize two figures within a subplot. Basically, I want a subplot with a temperature profile at 111 and a pressure profile at 211. However, I want the pressure figure to be smaller than the temperature figure. is this possible without the rather complicated gridspec lib? I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# ------Pressure------#

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('Pressure1.csv',index_col = None)
df1['P'] = df1['P'].str.split('.').str[:-1].str.join(',').str.replace(',', '.').astype(np.float64)
a = df1['T']
a /= 2900 # Convert milliseconds to hours
initial_time = 0
a += initial_time - min(a)
b = df1['P']
b -=+1 #convert from volts to bar

# ------- Temperature----------#

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('Temperature1.csv',index_col = None)

w = df['Time']
w /= 3600000 # Convert milliseconds to hours
initial_time = 0
w += initial_time - min(w)

x = df['Input 1']
y = df['Input 2']
z = df['Input 3']

#----subplot----#

plt.subplot(1,1,1)
figsize(20,10)
plt.plot(w,x, label = "Top_sensor")
plt.plot(w,y, label = "Mid_sensor")
plt.plot(w,z, label = 'Bot_sensor')
plt.title('Temperature')
plt.xlabel('Time(Hours)')
plt.ylabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.ylim(70, 200)
plt.xlim(0, 12, 1)
plt.show()

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
figsize(20,3)
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.title('Pressure_Monitoring')
plt.xlabel('Time(Hours)')
plt.ylabel('Pressure (Bar)')
plt.xlim(0, 12, 1)
plt.show()
```

See how I try to change the figsize in each subplot. Is this the wrong way?

Okay, so i've managed to get the gridspec i want. But, how do i combine the two?

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

f = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1,width_ratios=[20,10], height_ratios=[10,5])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :])` and `ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :])`.

Comment: how do i use the ax1 and ax2 when using my own datasets?

Comment: `plt.set_axes(ax1)` and `plt.set_axes(ax2)`?

Comment: plt.axes(ax1) worked :) thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why the `pyplot` interface is so bad. This is way more complicated than it needs to be.

Load and prepare your data. Then:

```
fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(20, 3))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, width_ratios=[20,10], height_ratios=[10,5])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])

ax1.plot(...)
ax1.set_ylabel(...)
...

ax2.plot(...)
ax2.set_xlabel(...)
```

That way, you don't have to create any extraneous objects that don't really get used and it's always explicit as to which axes is being modified.

Comment: A much nicer interface than pyplot indeed! However, when I tried to run the code above I got two errors. 1) `plt.Figure` should be lower case `plt.figure` 2) for a 2x1 grid, the width should be defined as a single value list since there is only one width to set, so `width_ratios=[20]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :])
```

and then set your axes like so:

```
plt.axes(ax1)
```

Comment: wouldn't it just be better to actually plot against the `ax1` and `ax2`? (i.e., ax`.plot(...)`

Comment: @PaulH yes, I would agree with you. I also agree with what you stated in your response that `pyplot` does not provide a very good interface which causes an overcomplicating of simple plots and inserts too much ambiguity on how to configure that same simple plot.

Comment: As @PaulH says, this is the case where the OO interface is much easier to use.  While this isn't _wrong_ I am tempted to down vote because it is bad practice.